# Reshaping pandas DataFrame from long to wide while adding many columns

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, reshape

I have a long DataFrame `df` in the following format:

```
user_id day action1 action2 action3 action4 action5
      1   0       4       2       0       1       0
      1   1       4       2       0       1       0
      2   1       4       2       0       1       0
```

The values in the action columns represent the number of times the user took that action on that day. I would like to translate this into a wide `DataFrame` but be able to extend the time frame arbitrarily (say, to 365 days).

I can reshape to wide fairly easily with:

```
df_indexed = df.set_index(['user_id', 'day'])
df_wide = df_indexed.unstack().fillna()
```

How would I go about adding the remaining 358 days filled with 0 for each of the five actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your MultiIndexed DataFrame, create a new index with `itertools.product` combining all the users from your DataFrame and all the days you want, and then just replace the index filling the missing values with 0.

```
import itertools

users = df.user_id.unique()
df_indexed = df.set_index(['user_id', 'day'])
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(itertools.product(users, range(365))))
reindexed = df_indexed.reindex(index, fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's something similar to what @ViktorKerkez suggested using `pandas.merge`

```
In [83]: df
Out[83]:
   user_id  day  action1  action2  action3  action4  action5
0        1    0        4        2        0        1        0
1        1    1        4        2        0        1        0
2        2    1        4        2        0        1        0

In [84]: days_joiner = DataFrame(dict(zip(['user_id', 'day'], zip(*list(itertools.product(df.user_id.unique(), range(365)))))))

In [85]: result = pd.merge(df, days_joiner, how='outer')

In [86]: result.head(10)
Out[86]:
   user_id  day  action1  action2  action3  action4  action5
0        1    0        4        2        0        1        0
1        1    1        4        2        0        1        0
2        2    1        4        2        0        1        0
3        1    2      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
4        1    3      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
5        1    4      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
6        1    5      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
7        1    6      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
8        1    7      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
9        1    8      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN

In [87]: result.fillna(0).head(10)
Out[87]:
   user_id  day  action1  action2  action3  action4  action5
0        1    0        4        2        0        1        0
1        1    1        4        2        0        1        0
2        2    1        4        2        0        1        0
3        1    2        0        0        0        0        0
4        1    3        0        0        0        0        0
5        1    4        0        0        0        0        0
6        1    5        0        0        0        0        0
7        1    6        0        0        0        0        0
8        1    7        0        0        0        0        0
9        1    8        0        0        0        0        0
```

To be fair: here's a `%timeit` comparison of the two methods

```
In [90]: timeit pd.merge(df, days_joiner, how='outer')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.33 ms per loop

In [96]: timeit df_indexed.reindex(index, fill_value=0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 146 µs per loop
```

My answer is slower by about 9x!